# Accessing different host from separate front-end (cross origin)

Tags: security, cross-domain

I've built a website with frontend in Polymer (no backend logic) and backend with Symfony and data given only through various APIs.

I have run it on chrome with

> -args --disable-web-security

now, after upgrading chrome it doesn't work. What should I do to allow access to separate backend on a separate server that would be considered a good practice?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add this header to your API responses?

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://your.client.domain
```